# update a VIRTUAL GENERATED column

Tags: mysql

```
UPDATE reservation SET NB_RESTE=1 WHERE IDRESERVATION='28'
```

i want to update the NB_RESTE value but it wont work , even when i try to update another column it works properly Knowing that NB_RESTE is VIRTUAL GENERATED

error message :

> #3105 - The value specified for generated column 'NB_RESTE' in table 'reservation' is not allowed.

Comment: Why do you want to updated a generated column directly? Update the field(s) it is generated from.

Comment: If you want to update the generated column to a value that no longer complies with its definition (e.g. you calculate the total amount from price and quantity and now you want to apply a 10+ item discount) then a generated column is not the right tool—not at least without some changes.

Answer (score 10):

As mysql manual on [update statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) says:

> If a generated column is updated explicitly, the only permitted value is DEFAULT.

Which is completely logical, since the value of the field is generated by an expression. In case of a virtual volumn, there is not even a value stored in the table. If you want to change the value of a generated column, then update the field(s) it is generated from.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual generated columns cannot be altered to stored generated columns, or vice versa. To work around this, drop the column, then add it with the new definition.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT, c2 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (c1 + 1) VIRTUAL);
ALTER TABLE t1 DROP COLUMN c2;
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN c2 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (c1 + 1) STORED;
```

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/alter-table-generated-columns.html